# How to stop javascript/jquery from executing when another function call is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My understanding of JavaScript is not super great, but I've been trying to use it to make some interactive features on my kids' website, [experimonkey.com](https://www.experimonkey.com/). One of my latest ideas was to have menu items on the homepage popup with additional information using JQuery's *toggle()* function when the user hovers over the corresponding menu item. This almost accomplishes what I want to do, except if you start hovering over the links too quickly, things get weird really fast... every single function call gets executed to completion and the browser starts to lag.

Is there a way to fix this so that only one element is in the queue at a time? Am I going about this totally wrong to begin with? Below is a sample of the code I'm using.

```js
function show(id) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#" + id).slideToggle();
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-6  col-sm-4 col-lg-2 tile p-1">
  <a href="/edu-center" onmouseenter="show('edu-center')" onmouseout="show('edu-center')">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="tile-edu-center"></div>
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h5>Edu-center</h5>
        <small id="edu-center" class="hidden">Science research and information for kids</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have written the js function insdie onReady() it will execute whenever there is a change made in the particular page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to make use of the `:hover` pseudo-class. Now, for the animation, you can use the `max-height`.

```css
.hidden {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

small {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover small {
  max-height: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-6  col-sm-4 col-lg-2 tile p-1">
  <a href="/edu-center">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="tile-edu-center"></div>
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h5>Edu-center</h5>
        <small id="edu-center" class="hidden">Science research and information for kids</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking it would be so nice to be able to just use hover here, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. What exactly is going on here with the "a:hover small" portion?

Comment: `a:hover small`, its straight forward, when `a` is on `hover` state, `small` inside `a` is targeted.

Comment: Oh I see. So hypothetically, if `small` wasn't contained within `a`, a similar solution wouldn't work?

Comment: nope, its hirerachy based. Fits your use-case i believe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`debounce`](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) to accomplish this. Basically, the debounce function delays the processing of event until the user has stopped for a predetermined amount of time. For example, use `debounce(onClick, 3000)` will only trigger onClick 2-times if two click actions is at least 3 seconds in between